# Auto renewable subscription in sandbox: renewal doesn't come after relaunch of App

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, sandbox, auto-renewing

I have a monthly auto-renewable subscription and it doesn't renew the subscription (update the receipt) in the sandbox environment -->  `func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction])` is not getting called. In the past, it worked fine with the following steps.

1) Create new sandbox user in App Store Connect (to enable 5 renewals)
2) Purchase the IAP (log in with new sandbox user)
3) Close the App
4) Reopen the App after 5 minutes  ---> receipt got updated in the past, but when I test it now it doesn't get updated at all after the initial purchase. (The update transactions aren't called in the sandbox.)

Any suggestions on how to fix that?

Comment: Do this problem still occures?

Answer (score 4):

According to various forum posts and some of my personal testing it seems that

1. One sandbox account will only get maximum of 5 renewal transactions per day. After that even if you purchase the same subscription, no renewal transaction will happen.
2. You need the app to *enter* foreground with an active observer, or you need to add an observer. Leaving the app open on foreground will not get you any transactions until the next time the app enters foreground.